# read specific part of a text file Ruby

Tags: ruby, text

Hi I convert a PDF to a txt file in Ruby 1.9.3

Here is part of the txt file:

```
    [["Rate", "Card", "February", "29,", "2012"]]
    [["Termination", "Color", "Test", "No", "Rate", "Currency", "Notes"]]
    [["x", "A", "CAMEL", "56731973573", "$", "0.1400", "USD", "30/45/100%"]]
    ["y", "A", "CARDINAL", "56731972501", "$", "0.1400", "USD", "30/45/100%"]]
    [["z", "A", "CARNELIAN", "56731971654", "$", "0.1400", "USD", "30/45/100%"]]
    .....
    ....
    [["Rate", "Card", "February", "29,", "2012"]]
    [["Termination", "Color", "Test", "No", "Rate", "Currency", "Notes"]]
```

I store every line in a different array, but the problem is that I don't want to read the two first lines which appears lots of times in my txt file, because those lines are the header in every page on the pdf. Any idea about how to do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read file into array and reject lines you do not need:

```
rejected = [
  '[["Rate", "Card", "February", "29,", "2012"]]',
  '[["Termination", "Color", "Test", "No", "Rate", "Currency", "Notes"]]',
]
lines = File.readlines('/path/to/file').reject { |line| rejected.include? line }
```